# failure: repodata/repomd.xml from libnvidia-container: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try

Tags: centos, drivers, nvidia, mirror, cuda

I followed the instructions from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive

```
sudo rpm -i cuda-repo-rhel7-8-0-local-ga2-8.0.61-1.x86_64-rpm
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install cuda
```

Now I get this error at the last step:

```
[jalal@goku GoodNews]$ sudo yum install cuda
[sudo] password for jalal: 
Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, copr, fastestmirror, kabi, langpacks, nvidia, priorities, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager, tmprepo, verify, versionlock

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Loading support for Red Hat kernel ABI
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * centos-sclo-rh: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.lug.udel.edu
 * remi-php70: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * remi-php71: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * remi-php73: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * remi-safe: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Atom/x86_64/signature                                                                                                   |  833 B  00:00:00     
Atom/x86_64/signature                                                                                                   | 1.0 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
WANdisco-git                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
adobe-linux-x86_64                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
base                                                                                                                    | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
carlwgeorge-ripgrep                                                                                                     | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
centos-sclo-rh                                                                                                          | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
centos-sclo-sclo                                                                                                        | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
code                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
cs                                                                                                                      | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
cuda-8-0-local-ga2                                                                                                      | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
docker-ce-stable                                                                                                        | 3.5 kB  00:00:00     
epel                                                                                                                    | 4.7 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
google-chrome                                                                                                           | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
ius                                                                                                                     | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
jknife-ue4deps                                                                                                          | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
libnvidia-container/x86_64/signature                                                                                    |  488 B  00:00:00     
Retrieving key from https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey
libnvidia-container/x86_64/signature                                                                                    | 2.1 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/centos7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for libnvidia-container
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (libnvidia-container),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=libnvidia-container ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable libnvidia-container
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=libnvidia-container

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=libnvidia-container.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from libnvidia-container: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/centos7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for libnvidia-container
```

I have the following:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61



$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
Release:    7.8.2003
Codename:   Core
```

and two 1080 Ti GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your yum repo with the one described [here](https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/):

https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/centos7/libnvidia-container.repo